# Web page from the terminal

Tags: macos, mac, browser, terminal.app

I use Snow Leopard. How I can send a html page to a web browser from Terminal.app?

If I am in $HOME dir, with a file myPage.html, can I view this file in a browser right from Terminal.app?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, to **open a file** from the Mac OS X terminal you can use the `open` command. This is the same as double-clicking on the file to open it.

You can specify the application to use for opening the file with the `-a` option. If not specified, the default application set via LaunchServices is used to open the file <sup>(1)</sup>.

In your case, **to open a HTML file with a browser from the terminal**, use this command:

```
$ open -a /Applications/YourBrowser.app YourFile.html
```

Or, you can omit the`-a` option...

```
$ open YourFile.html
```

...to open it with the default browser. <sup>(2)</sup>

---

<sup>1)</sup> : Usually this is the application that was used to create the file. You can change this via the "Get info..." window. (Select the file, then hit <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>.)

<sup>2)</sup> : Be aware that this method may not work depending on the application set to open the file. This may be done for one or for all files. Typically, on a web developer computer, the application set to open HTML files will likely be a text or code editor.

Comment: FYI, Snow Leopard drops the creator types, so the second command would generally open in the default browser unless the individual file has a different application set to open it from the Get Info window.

Comment: @Kio Dane: Nice point, amended some details about it.

Comment: Does the open command halt input into the terminal until the corresponding process has terminated? I mean, if I wanted firefox to open up hello.html, but continue using the terminal window I would do firefox hello.html& to launch it in the background, but since I don't have a Mac, I would like to know how this works.

Comment: @Nitrodist: No. You actually don't launch Firefox or another app in a child process. You ask Firefox to open itself and load the file just as if you had double-clicked on it from the Finder.